# What could make WildFly undeploy automatically an EAR?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I have an application hosted in WildFly 8.2.1.Final and after some days it undeploy automatically my EAR.

The server is started with `./standalone.sh` and the EAR is deployed putting the ear in the `standalone/deployments` folder along with `.dodeploy` file.

The last lines of `server.log` shows:

```
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017535: Unregistered web context: /App
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017535: Unregistered web context: /AppPortal
INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'AppEAR.ear/AppEJB.jar#AppEJB'
INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment AppEAR.ear
INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'AppEAR.ear/AppEJB.jar#AppEJB'
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: AppService.war) in 233ms
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: AppEJB.jar) in 233ms
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: AppPortal.war) in 237ms
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment AppEAR.ear (runtime-name: AppEAR.ear) in 336ms
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018558: Undeployed "AppEAR.ear" (runtime-name: "AppEAR.ear")
```

After that, neither management console works at `localhost:9990`.

Comment: How is the application deployed to begin with, and what type of deployments is the server allowing? Is it done by putting the ear in the standalone/deployments folder?

Comment: @Gimby, please see the detailed question edits

Comment: After the undeployment happens, what files are there in the deployments folder?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found out that I had Linux cron job running that was reloading WildFly. This may not be your case, but check your cron jobs just in case.

Here is the log output I was getting.

```
2022-11-26 03:30:27,110 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "stych.war")
2022-11-26 03:30:27,110 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "stych-ejb.jar")
2022-11-26 03:30:27,986 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment stych.ear
2022-11-26 03:30:28,092 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.22.Final
2022-11-26 03:30:28,225 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment stych-ejb.jar
2022-11-26 03:30:28,271 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment stych.war
2022-11-26 03:30:28,460 INFO  [io.jaegertracing.internal.JaegerTracer] (MSC service thread 1-7) No shutdown hook registered: Please call close() manually on application shutdown.
2022-11-26 03:30:28,517 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) WELD-000900: 3.1.5 (Final)
2022-11-26 03:30:28,627 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYRS0018: Explicit usage of Jackson annotation in a JAX-RS deployment; the system will disable JSON-B processing for the current deployment. Consider setting the 'resteasy.preferJacksonOverJsonB' property to 'false' to restore JSON-B.
2022-11-26 03:30:28,782 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Corona Extra' 11.0.8.Final
2022-11-26 03:30:28,859 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
2022-11-26 03:30:28,861 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
2022-11-26 03:30:28,991 INFO  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.marshalling.InfinispanProtoStreamMarshaller'
2022-11-26 03:30:29,186 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) WFLYCLINF0002: Started http-remoting-connector cache from ejb container
2022-11-26 03:30:29,807 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.stych.backend.rest.RestApplication
2022-11-26 03:30:29,807 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJacksonProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
2022-11-26 03:30:29,825 WARN  [org.jboss.as.weld] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) WFLYWELD0052: Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core, org.jboss.weld.spi, org.jboss.weld.api]
2022-11-26 03:30:30,034 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/' for server 'default-server'
2022-11-26 03:30:30,091 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "stych.ear" (runtime-name : "stych.ear")
2022-11-26 03:30:30,136 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
2022-11-26 03:30:30,139 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 22.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 14.0.1.Final) started in 8464ms - Started 516 of 718 services (356 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2022-11-26 03:30:30,140 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
2022-11-26 03:30:30,140 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
<------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
            10 MINUTES LATER EVERYTHING GOT UNREGISTERED FOR AN UNKNOWN REASON
<------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
2022-11-26 03:40:08,103 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
2022-11-26 03:40:08,113 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/' from server 'default-server'
2022-11-26 03:40:08,136 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
2022-11-26 03:40:08,143 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
2022-11-26 03:40:08,151 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
2022-11-26 03:40:08,164 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped http-remoting-connector cache from ejb container
2022-11-26 03:40:08,168 INFO  [org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) Stopping cache manager null on null
2022-11-26 03:40:08,185 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
2022-11-26 03:40:08,185 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: stych-ejb.jar) in 99ms
2022-11-26 03:40:08,185 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8080
```